# Node.js S3 Upload: Setting Content Type for Multiple File Types (PDF, XML) without Explicitly Specifying Each Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload files of type PDF and XML, but i dont know hot to do it, i have an idea of using the path setting a switch but I think there's another way I read this and the answer was

`ContentType: 'application/octet-stream'`

But I don't know it this is the correct answer

I attach the code

Help with setting the type content

Comment: `application/octet-stream` is the most generic content type available; it simply means a series of 8-bit values (bytes). S3 shouldn't care what content type you provide it with; `application/octet-stream` should be perfectly fine for both pdf and xml as far as I'm aware!

Comment: Thank you very much!! it helped me a lot!

Comment: Awesome, good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

I used the path module

```
const getContentType = (fileExtension) => {
  const ext = path.extname(fileExtension).toLowerCase();
  let contentType = '';
  if (ext === '.pdf') {
    contentType = 'application/pdf';
  } else if (ext === '.xml') {
    contentType = 'application/xml';
  } else {
    contentType = null;
  }
  return contentType;
};
```

if you know how to this with another approach, please let me know